# Update label.text from another class

Tags: swift, uilabel

I have a view controller with a label ("titre") and a button.

```
class PresentationViewController: UIViewController, UIScrollViewDelegate,SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKRequestDelegate  {

@IBOutlet weak var titre: UILabel!

 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

        if !defaults.bool(forKey: "XXXXXX.\(GlobalVariables.sharedinstance.circuitselectionne!)"){
           titre.text = "2,90€"
       }

        else {
           titre.text = "Démarrer la visite !  "
        }
```

When this button is triggered, a function in another class is launched.

In this function, we define the boolean of the variable checked in the initial viewController.

```
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.set(true,forKey:"XXXXXX.\(nomtelechargementàajouter)")
```

But when it's done, `titre.text` is not updated in my Viewcontroller.
So how could I refresh the value of `titre.text` in the ViewController?

Another point is this function could be called in other ViewController.

Any idea?

Comment: Can you show the full code? You just showed 1 line

Comment: @Hugo75, can you reformat your code? I can't find where you function is called. Please provide code by a clear way.

Comment: I ve tried to be the most concise and clear because it's a lot of pages of code. (In app purchase code) The question is : if i define a variable in another class, how could i refresh the "titre.text" if ViewController was already called.

Comment: you have to put if else condition inside a function and call that function everytime you change the UserDefaults value, then your label text will set each time the value changes. Because right now you set label text in viewDidLoad function which is only called once in view lifecycle.

Comment: Exact Rishabh, so is there no possibilities to refresh the viewController ? I ve tried viewWillAppear And viewDidAppear, but it's not called...

Comment: use NotificationCenter, you can add observer and trigger notification to update changes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use **Notifications and observers** to control your code behavior between your data and your controllers.
On the end of your function that define the boolean variable that you check in the viewDidload of your viewController post a notification like this :

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "VariableDefined"), object: nil)
```

With this you create a notification called *VariableDefined* (you can name it as you want). *object* parameter allows you to send data or whatever parameter you want with this notification.
Then, you have to set up a listener to listen to this notification. Who is interested on your boolean variable ? **Your viewController**.
Put a listener of this notification on your view controller like this :

```
let name = Notification.Name(rawValue: "VariableDefined")
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
    self, selector: #selector(checkVariable), 
    name: name, object: nil)
```

With this you are defining a listener to the notification called VariableDefined and handle it with the method `checkVariable`.
Finally, on this handler you can update your label title :

```
func checkVariable() {
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    if !defaults.bool(forKey: "XXXXXX.\
       (GlobalVariables.sharedinstance.circuitselectionne!)"){
       titre.text = "2,90€"
    } else {
       titre.text = "Démarrer la visite !  "
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you. That's a way to communicate between models and view controllers.